# Opening and closing a door properly Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine

```
 public GameObject doorHinge;
    public bool doorIsOpen;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.E))
        {
            doorHinge.transform.Rotate(0.0f, -90f, 0.0f);
            doorIsOpen = true;
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.E) && (doorIsOpen == true))
        {
            doorHinge.transform.Rotate(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
            doorIsOpen = false;
        }
    }
```

I have very basic code. The door opens as it should after I press E with the correct rotation, but instead of going back to its default position, it turns -90 degrees 4 times.

That's why I put the bool there so shouldn't that prevent the door from turning the wrong way?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have a fundamental misunderstanding of what the Rotate function does.

```
doorHinge.transform.Rotate(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
```

The above code is similar to the `+=` assignment. Which means you say `rotation += 0`. If you want to set the rotation value, then you should use `rotation` instead of `Rotate`

To fix your code, you should have

```
doorHinge.transform.Rotate(0.0f, 90f, 0.0f);
```

or

```
doorHinge.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Identity;
```

You might benefit from watching some free classes on [Unity Learn](https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/translate-and-rotate#) or using google more aggressively.